# Connecting both local & remotely MYSQL

Tags: mysql, ubuntu, lamp

I have 2 ubuntu servers lets say X and Y. My sql server is on X. I want to be able to connect and use my database both locally(X) and remotely (Y). I read bunch of tutorials and questions here and I commented out these lines in my.cf as such:

```
#Bind-address 127.0.0.1
#skip-networking
```

Then did this:

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'USERNAME'@'IP of Y' IDENTIFIED BY 'PASSWORD' WITH GRANT OPTION;
```

But when I do this I get this error when i want to connect locally.

> ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysql.sock'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems I just had to restart mysql service and it worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to connect both locally and remote with the same user you need to create the same user twice one with local host and one with % wildcard
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/adding-users.html

```
CREATE USER 'USER'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'some_pass';

CREATE USER 'USER'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'some_pass';
```

Then GRANT rights for both options

Comment: @HiradRoshandel It still needs 2 accounts one with the ip you are going to connect from

Answer (score 0):

Put mysqld to listen on all interfaces :-D

**In my.cnf:**

```
Bind-address 0.0.0.0
```

and

```
socket          = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock (access local)
port            = 3306
```